# Error función document.getElementsByTagName() con OnClick

Tags: javascript, html5

mi función `document.getElementsByTagName()` no me permite generar el evento `OnClick` en un texto.

Aquí mi código `HTML`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>

<script src="archivo_script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <p>Algo de texto 1</p>
    <p>Algo de texto 2</p>
    <p>Algo de texto 3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Código que está en el archivo externo `JavaScript` (archivo_script.js)

```
function ejecuta(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].onclick=saludo;
}
function saludo(){
    alert("Que hay de nuevo");
}
window.onload=ejecuta;
```

Comment: prueba mover el `window.onload=ejecuta;` al html principal

Comment: Te tendría que funcionar, revisa que tengas el archivo js al mismo nivel que el archivo html. Si estas en chrome presiona F12 y mira a ver si te suelta algún error, ya que en principio lo tienes bien.

Comment: A mi tal cual lo tienes me funciona, así que imagino que tu navegador, por lo que sea, bloquea el JS, o como mínimo, tu JS...

Comment: He estado intentando hacer funcionar el código y también buscando en otras fuentes. El código funciona hasta el punto de reconocer el Id de los Tag <p>. Pero el "evento onclick" no me funciona con ningún navegador. He visto otras formas de hacerlo con botones y anda bien. Adjunto imágenes de mi código HTML5 y JS https://ibb.co/n9juin y https://ibb.co/ceL0On .

Comment: En este caso https://ibb.co/kBHa67 puse algunos alert() enumerados 1, 2, 3 y 4 (para ver el flujo del codigo)y al parecer no estaba ingresando la "funcion ejecuta", ni a la "funcion saludo". Lo que hice fue agregarle los parentesis a dichas funciones que se ven en esta ultima foto y puedo ingresar hasta el final, pero nunca lanza el alerta numero 3, solo lanza 1,2 y 4. Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Te da algún error en la consola? A mí me funciona perfectamente. Al hacer click sobre el primer texto se ejecuta el alert del saludo. (He probado desde Chrome)

Comment: En la última imagen, ¿"importante" es una referencia a una clase, o a un id? Recuerda que para clases debería ser ".importante" (con el punto) y para ids "#importante" (con la almoadilla)

Comment: Además, los paréntesis deberías añadirlos solo al `window.onload = ejecuta();`

Comment: Holaaaa ya lo solucioné. Aparentemente es cuando se esta trabajando desde el disco "D" ninguno de los navegadores(chrome, moz, opera,explore) me permitian ejecutar el codigo. Luego tmb intente ejecutarlo desde DreamWeaver y tampoco me dejaba porque el mismo tmb esta en el disco "D" y al cambiarlo al disco C empezo a funcionar bien!.. gracias a todos lo que colaboraron para solucionar el error que me ocurria.